# How to pass an argument to an argument when executing a shell command from Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shell, command-line-arguments

In objective-c I can do the following:

```
NSTask* foo = [NSTask alloc]init];
[foo setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/open"];

[foo setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                @"/foo/foobar.app/foobarbinary,
                                nil]];  
// Arguments to the command: the name of the
// Applications directory

[foo launch];
// Run the command

[foo release];
```

The problem is, if foobarbinary accepts command line arguments, how do I pass them in? :)
If I add them to the NSArray, then the shell assumes they are an argument for "open". If I add it to the string, just after foobarbinary, (e.g.: @"foo/foobar.app/foobarbinary -someargument") , then "open" assumes that the name of the file is "foo/foobar.app/foobarbinary -someargument".

So how do I pass an argument to an argument? :S

EDIT. I tried using the --args command in the array. But it seems that foobarbinary doesn't receive the arguments I specify afar the --args. :S Anyone have an example I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `open` command won't let you do that. If you want to pass arguments to foobarbinary you have to launch it directly.

Comment: It works thanks! It didn't occur to me that you could directly call the binary like that. :S Have to wait two minutes to accept the answer. :)